# chart.scrollablePlotArea unexpected behavior

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

I'm trying to to add a `scrollBar` on `xAxis` through `chart.scrollablePlotArea` to my chart but it's not working as expected. I was having trouble to make it appear. The solution I found was to remove `containerProps` from my `react-component`

```js
containerProps={{
  className: "chart",
  style: {
    height: "500px",
    minWidth: "280px"
  }
}}
```

With that the `scrollBar` appeared, but some unexpected behaviors occured, first the `fullScreen` broke (It started showing up black bars), second the `customButton` started moving around with the chart. I searched on `exporting.buttons.contextButton` [API](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.buttons.contextButton) but couldn't find any property to fix its position.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/scrollableplotarea-bugs-dm9et?file=/src/CustomGUIChart.js:1001-1076) is a working demo, appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

> The solution I found was to remove containerProps from my react-component

It seems that `scrollablePlotArea` works fine without removing the `containerProps`, but the container width must be smaller than set `scrollablePlotArea.minWidth`.

> first the fullScreen broke (It started showing up black bars)

It is a bug which has been already fixed. Will available in the Highcharts npm after the next release.

https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/12832

> second the customButton started moving around with the chart

How did you find this feature? It seems that `customButton` is not available in the API, which means that is not fully supported.

Comment: What is the container width? the one defined on `cointainerProps`? I was trying with that width smaller than `scrollablePlotArea.minWidth`, going on mobile view would allow me to scroll it with touch gesture but there was no scrollbar. About the `customBotton` I'm not sure, probably found it as a workaround on some old forum post.

Comment: Yes, the container width could be set in the `containerProps`. By saying the container width I had in mind any style width options set on the container. The `scrollablePlotArea.minWidth` is a value under which scrollablePlotArea feature is applied. So if you don't have the fixed style width value (the chart is responsive) feature will be applied only if width has been changed to a lower value.